# Overriding setter methods (strong vs. assign) using ARC

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

When defining a `strong` property in an interface, like so:

`@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *petColor;`

It is no longer required to add `@synthesize`, or `@dynamic`, or to manually define the internal ivar as `_petColor`, this all just works. The setters/getters are automatically generated, and you can access `_petColor` internally without any additional code.

*However,* I'm a little confused as to how (if at all), when overriding a setter, ARC knows whether to insert the retain/release calls depending on whether the property is `strong` or `weak`? For example, if I have **two** properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *petColor;
@property (nonatomic, weak) SomeClass *petDelegate;
```

If I want to override the setters for these properties, it seems they would be almost exactly the same?

```
- (void)setPetColor:(UIColor *)theColor {
    if (![theColor isEqual:petColor]) {
        _petColor = theColor;
    }
}

- (void)setPetDelegate:(SomeClass *)theDel {
    if (theDel != petDelegate) {
        _petDelegate = theDel;
    }
}
```

Is this correct? And if so, is ARC automatically inserting the proper `retain/release` calls in both of those setters, or only in the overridden setter for the `strong` property?

**Further:** Does the `weak` property behavior *differ*, in this situation, from the `assign` property behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's even simpler than that. When synthesizing, the instance variables get the respective qualifiers:

```
@implementation MyClass {
    // this is what is added by the auto synthesize
    UIColor * __strong _petColor;
    SomeClass * __weak _petDelegate;
}
```

So when you assign to the instance variables using own setters, everything is fine, except for the `copy` qualifier. That one cannot be used for an instance variable, so then assign a copy to the instance variable.

Regarding `assign` (or the equivalent `unsafe_unretained`) for object properties, the instance variable would just be a pointer, and be synthesized to

```
    SomeClass * __unsafe_unretained _petDelegate;
```

So if the object assigned to the property is deallocated, the pointer would not be set to `nil` as with weak, but point to where the deallocated object lived before. That may lead to crashes. As a rule of thumb, if you write your code for iOS 5 or later, always use `weak` instead of `assign` or `unsafe_unretained` on object properties.

Comment: Thanks - the fact that the ivars themselves are qualified explains how ARC is able to know what to do during the assignment. (Thanks also for the UIColor note - question updated.)

Comment: I also added some info on `assign` vs `weak`.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `strong`, `weak`, or `assign` attributes of a property tells the compiler the storage class of the underlying data. If that is an auto-generated iVar, then it maps as following:

- strong -> __strong
- weak -> __weak
- assign -> __unsafe_unretained

If you don't use an auto-generated iVar, then whatever data you have feeding the property is expected to conform to those storage class mappings.

See: [Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) : Property declarations](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#property-declarations)